# Is there a solution to handle native errors or crashes without eject Expo?

Tags: react-native, error-handling, expo, eas

I'm novice on React Native development, so I chosed to use Expo.
It seems very convinient, but I can't find a way to handle the case when native error occurs.
I wanted to use 'setNativeExceptionHandler' from "react-native-exception-handler", but I can't use it because it causes "Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable." since it's native package and I can't link it to my project while I'm keeping it under Expo.

So I'm wondering,

1. Is there any solution or workaround to handle the native error without ejecting Expo?
2. If there's zero possibility, and if I keep the Expo development environment, what should I do? Is it possible to do like this? "complete everything under Expo -> eject -> insert native error handler -> EAS build" and repeat it every time(modify from the version before eject) when I update the app...?
3. Or, It's unnecessary because the developers can check the crash info in the App store or Play store?